# Overflowing numerical data on SSIS from CSV file

Tags: csv, ssis, type-conversion, overflow

So, I need to load data from a CSV file into SQL Server, but I'm facing an issue that I can't seem to overcome. The problem is, some of the data points on the CSV are really really precise, with 38 decimal digits + one or two whole digits (e.g. 89.95849436456480407115801673479014153261), and I can't seem to load them without overflowing the data. The data comes in as text, and I've tryed to convert it up to Numeric(38,38), which is the maximum, on the Data Conversion step, but it's still not enough and keeps overflowing. Here's part of the error message:

```
Error: 0xC02020C5 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: Data conversion failed while converting column "%Recycle Matl Week" (216) to column "%Recycle Matl Week" (61).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Data Conversion [2]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[%Recycle Matl Week]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data Conversion.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[%Recycle Matl Week]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data Conversion" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Data Conversion Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

I'm really stuck at this one, I always feel like it's a simple solution but just can't get it. Changing the CSV from the source is a no deal, but I really don't need that much precision here (8 decimal digits is enough). I appreciate any help I can get, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With DECIMAL(38,38) you aren't leaving any space for the digits in front of the decimal so you will overflow

When using DECIMAL data type The first number is the amount of numbers allowed in the field and the second number is how many of those numbers are allowed to be decimal

For example

- DECIMAL (5,4)

  - 1.2345 will work
  - 12.345 will fail because you are only leaving one digit in front and 4 after, 2 digits in front will overflow
    [image]
- DECIMAL (5,1)

  - 1.2345 will work but be rounded to 1.2, overflow after the decimal will round up to fit
  - 12.345 will work but be rounded to 12.3
  - 12345.6 will fail because the decimal 1 takes up one space, so you only have 4 digits in front of the decimal.

In your case you need at least two digits in front of the decimal so DECIMAL(38,36) will work

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(38,36),'89.95849436456480407115801673479014153261')
```

[image: SQL]

Answer (score 0):

The CONVERT solution also doesn't work, as there were still 38 decimal digits in some data points, plus whole digits, still overflowing. I tried using double floats but it also didn't work. But I managed a workaround using an auxiliary table:

I started with an auxiliary step creating and populating a similar table on SQL Server, but with all data as VARCHAR instead of NUMERICAL. Then, I changed the SQL code I was using using LEFT to cut the data and CAST to convert to numerical. For instance:

```
CAST(
    CAST(LEFT([Total Weight Var %],12) AS DECIMAL(13,8)) / 100 
AS DECIMAL(13,8)) AS OVER_WEIGHT_PCT,
```

It was not the most elegant solution, but it worked.

Comment: You cloud have achieved this without the additional table simply by reading as VARCHAR and trim the same way in a Derived Column in your Data Flow,